# Telegram bot для выдачи ифн. Выдает ошибку

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пробую себя в написании телеграмм бота. Начал с основ и не могу понять в чем ошибка у меня при работе. Вроде все должно работать но по непонятной причине выдает ошибку при обращении к функ get_age
Мой код:

После того как я ввожу фамилию, БОТ выдает мне такую ошибку

> bot.send_message('Сколько тебе лет?'); TypeError: send_message()
>   missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

Как можно исправить ? (Извините если где-то пробел не правильный, на сайт скинул с пробелами, а потом пришлось в ручную пробелы ставить)

```
import telebot;
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('ТОКЕН');

name = '';
surname = '';
age = 0;
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == '/reg':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Как тебя зовут?");
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name); #следующий шаг – функция get_name
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напиши /reg');

def get_name(message): #получаем фамилию
    global name;
    name = message.text;
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какая у тебя фамилия?');
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_surname);

def get_surname(message):
    global surname;
    surname = message.text;
    bot.send_message('Сколько тебе лет?');
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_age);

def get_age(message):
    global age;
    while age == 0: #проверяем что возраст изменился
        try:
             age = int(message.text) #проверяем, что возраст введен корректно
        except Exception:
             bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Цифрами, пожалуйста');
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(); #наша клавиатура
    key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='yes'); #кнопка «Да»
    keyboard.add(key_yes); #добавляем кнопку в клавиатуру
    key_no= types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='no');
    keyboard.add(key_no);
    question = 'Тебе '+str(age)+' лет, тебя зовут '+name+' '+surname+'?';
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=question, reply_markup=keyboard)



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "yes": #call.data это callback_data, которую мы указали при объявлении кнопки
    ... #код сохранения данных, или их обработки
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Запомню : )');
    elif call.data == "no":
     ... #переспрашиваем
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: 1) `;` не нужно в питоне ставить 2) У вас опечатка выше уже используете аналогичный метод: `bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какая у тебя фамилия?')`, т.е. нужно указывать первым параметром `message.from_user.id`

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция send_message(), имеет первый аргумент чат.id, а второй текстовый. Вы напросто теряете аргумент.